# How to use Optional chaining correctly in the unknown

Tags: typescript

demo:

```
function getValue(data: unknown) {
  // return data?.value // error
  // or
  // use "value" in data to narrow the scope
  if (typeof data === 'object' && data && 'value' in data) {
    return data.value; // error
  }
  return '';
}
```

I don't want to use assertions
data is similar to the data returned by a request

Comment: Are you looking for ```return data?.value ?? '';```?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot do it this simply right now, typescript isn't able to infer types from the `in` operator very well at the moment. Either use type assertions or you could write a type guard like `const hasValue = (obj: any): obj is {value: unknown} => typeof obj === 'object' && obj && 'value' in obj` and then use it `if(hasValue(data))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex Chashin commented，typescript isn't able to infer types from the in operator very well at the moment.So maybe I need this function

```
function hasValue(it: unknown): it is ({ value: string }) {
    return typeof it === "object" && it !== null && "value" in it;
}

function hasStringValue(it: unknown): it is ({ value: string }) {
    return hasValue(it) && typeof it.value === "string";
}
```

[Using type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic types.
For example:

```
type IData = {value: string}

function getValue<T extends IData>(data: T) {
  if (typeof data === 'object' && data && 'value' in data) {
    return data.value;
  }
  return '';
}
```